# Keep dynamically added tabs in shiny after page refresh

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity, shinyjs

I built an app that uses the PrependTab function to allow users to add new tabs. Right now, the function successfully adds the TabPanels but when I refresh the page they disappear.

Is there any way to keep the new dynamically added tabs in the same session even after refreshing ?

Thanks !

Comment: This is a tricky one, with my limited understanding of HTML, when you refresh the page, the browser redownloads the source code. Mind you, what you see in the browser comes from instructions (i.e. source code), which is saved on the server. So to keep the dynamically added tabs, you have to save the edited source code somewhere and tell the browser to load the code from there on refresh and not from your server.